# (Workbooks.Open) works not like normal opening

Tags: excel, vba

I have a really strange problem that the numbers change alone in the first column when I try to open it in VBA with (Workbooks.open). All numbers ended with "000", although the original values had only 2 digits. I tried to convert the numbers to text after opening it in VBA but it is still not working.

```
Dim wk As Excel.Workbook, sh As Worksheet 
hDrive "C:"
     ChDir "C:\DOKU\SAP"
        File = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Mappen (*.xls),*.xls")
    If File = False Then Exit Sub

Set wk = Application.Workbooks.Open(file, 0, ReadOnly:=True, Format:=1, CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile)
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Windows(file).Activate
    sh.Range("A:D").NumberFormat = "@"
```

#### Opening file in VBA:

[image: opening file in VBA]

#### Normal opening:

[image: normal opening]

Comment: I'm confused - those are the same numbers, just different formats. Are they supposed to be text?

Comment: How about using `sh.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "0"` instead?

Comment: Check the format of the column when opening in normal and set a line of code to make the format the same using code

Comment: What happen if you change  sh.Range("A:D").NumberFormat = "@" to sh.Range("A:D").NumberFormat = "General"

Answer (score 0):

For non US-users, set the Workbooks.Open method parameter "Local" to True.
The default (False) correspond to US English and will format numbers with a coma as a decimal separator (and a number of digits after the coma different than 3) to text as well as some dates (the order of the days and months is mixed up, leading to impossible dates eg 31/12/2019 in mm/dd/yyyy)